# which mixer should I use to grind idli batter in USA?

Tags: indian-cuisine

I have been struggling with making soft idlis. I live in the US. I have tried many recipes but none of them gave soft idlis. I suspect it might be because of the grainy batter. I am using Ninja blender to grind daal and rice (separately). Any recommendations for good mixie so that my batter is smooth? Also, do I need to special rice (sona masuri) for idli/poha? I use basmati rice.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Please ask one question at a time.  SInce you asked three, I'm going to answer the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want smooth idly batter, you need to use a [Wet Grinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_grinder_(food)), like [an Elgi](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Elgi-Ultra-Dura-Table-Top-Wet-Grinder-1-25-Liter/127370770).  The rotary grinding stone action of these produces a much smoother, stickier batter than any blender can.  They're also good for making chocolate.